# Sequence $A_n$ converges to $\phi$ iff the sequence of symmetric difference $B_n=B_{n-1}\Delta A_n$ is convergent

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $B_1=A_1$ and $B_n=B_{n-1}\Delta A_n$ for $n=1,2,...$. Then $B_n$ is convergent iff $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}A_n=\phi$

The definition for convergence $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\inf A_n
=
\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\bigcap_{k=n}^\infty A_k
=
\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_k
=
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sup A_n$$

I know that $B_n=(B_{n-1}|A_n)\cup(A_n|B_{n-1})$ but I don't know where to start. Could you please give a small hint on how to start to prove this.

Comment: Could you include your definition of convergence for a sequence of sets?

Comment: Please **edit the question** to include this information.  Please also let us know your thoughts on a solution.  Have you been able to make progress on either side of the implication?

Comment: Again, please **edit the question** to insert this information.  You probably want to use the \setminus symbol in MathJax.